# Show that a finite group of even order that has a cyclic Sylow $2-$ subgroup is not simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

> Show that a finite group of even order that has a cyclic Sylow $2-$ subgroup is not simple.

**Attempt**:

Since $G$ has a Sylow $2$ subgroup so $|G|=2^km$ .

I don't know how to use the fact that the  Sylow $2-$ subgroup is cyclic.

Please give some hints.

Comment: Lemma 2 in [Tobias' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1666740/11619) to another question.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404906/elements-of-odd-order-form-a-subgroup-when-the-sylow-2-subgroup-is-cyclic/ which uses some more high-powered results.

Answer (score 2):

Let $2^km=n=|G|$, we have a permutation representation $$\varphi: G \to S_n$$ which corrsponds to left multiplication by $G$. So we treat $G$ as a subgroup of $S_n$. We claim that $G$ contains an odd permutation, hence half of $G$ is even, these elements form a subgroup of index 2, so $G$ cannot be simple.

To show $G$ indeed has odd permutation, note that under $\varphi$, a generator of a cyclic 2-Sylow must be $m$ disjoint products of $2^k$-cycle, which is an odd permutation.