# Group of order $2^n m$ ($m$ odd) with a cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup has a characteristic subgroup of order $m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

> Group of order $2^n m$ ($m$ odd) with a cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup has a characteristic subgroup of order $m$.

I'd like to approach this by induction, but I can't see how to go about it.  I'm stuck just on the case where $n=1$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404906/elements-of-odd-order-form-a-subgroup-when-the-sylow-2-subgroup-is-cyclic (the fact that the subgroup is characteristic rather than just normal follows from it having order coprime to its index).

Answer (score 0):

By Cayley's theorem, $G$ of order $2m$ has an embedding in $S_{2m}$
where all non-identity elements have no fixed points. In particular
elements of order $2$ have $m$ cycles of length $2$ and so are odd
permutations. Thus the elements of $G$ mapping to even permutations
form an index $2$ subgroup of $G$, which is clearly characteristic.